# Where do we define the type of structure returned by the kernel when using the "perf_event_open" system call using mmap?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, mmap, perf

I'm trying to use the syscall `perf_event_open` to get some performance data from the system.

I am currently working on periodic data retrieval using shared memory with a ring buffer.

But I can't find what structure is returned in each section of the ring buffer. The manual page enumerate all possibilities, but that's all.
I can't figure out which member of the `perf_event_attr` structure to fill in to control what type of structure will be returned to the ring buffer.

If you have some informations about that, I'll be happy to read it !

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code that you have written ? Read about [how to provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Read the https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/design.txt doc (it has some parts outdated, but still useful for `perf_event_open` syscall description). First mmap page is metadata, rest 2^n pages are filled with events where every event has header `struct perf_event_header` of 8 bytes: type:int32,misc:int16,size:int16

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/design.txt documentation has description of mmaped ring, and `perf script` / `perf script -D` can decode ring data when it is saved as perf.data file. Some parts of the doc are outdated, but it is still useful for `perf_event_open` syscall description.

First mmap page is metadata page, rest 2^n pages are filled with events where every event has header `struct perf_event_header` of 8 bytes.

> Like stated, asynchronous events, like counter overflow or PROT_EXEC
>   mmap tracking are logged into a ring-buffer. This ring-buffer is
>   created and accessed through mmap().
>
> The mmap size should be 1+2^n pages, where the first page is a
>   meta-data page (struct perf_event_mmap_page) that contains various
>   bits of information such as where the ring-buffer head is.
>
> ```
> /*
>  * Structure of the page that can be mapped via mmap
>  */
> struct perf_event_mmap_page {
>         __u32   version;                /* version number of this structure */
>         __u32   compat_version;         /* lowest version this is compat with */
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> The following 2^n pages are the ring-buffer which contains events of the form:
>
> ```
> #define PERF_RECORD_MISC_KERNEL          (1 << 0)
> #define PERF_RECORD_MISC_USER            (1 << 1)
> #define PERF_RECORD_MISC_OVERFLOW        (1 << 2)
>
> struct perf_event_header {
>         __u32   type;
>         __u16   misc;
>         __u16   size;
> };
>
> enum perf_event_type
> ```

The `design.txt` doc has incorrect values for enum perf_event_type, check actual perf_events kernel subsystem source codes - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L707. That uapi/linux/perf_event.h file also has some struct hints in comments, like

> ```
>  *    #
>  *  # The RAW record below is opaque data wrt the ABI
>  *  #
>  *  # That is, the ABI doesn't make any promises wrt to
>  *  # the stability of its content, it may vary depending
>  *  # on event, hardware, kernel version and phase of
>  *  # the moon.
>  *  #
>  *  # In other words, PERF_SAMPLE_RAW contents are not an ABI.
>  *  #
>  *
>  *  { u32           size;
>  *    char                  data[size];}&& PERF_SAMPLE_RAW
>  *...
>  *  { u64           size;
>  *    char          data[size];
>  *    u64           dyn_size; } && PERF_SAMPLE_STACK_USER
>  *...
> PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE          = 9,
> ```